# How to get the sum of the sum with one mysql query

Tags: mysql, sum

I have the following query which gives me back all grouped sales on publisher

```
SELECT 
   publisher_name, 
   SUM(sales) AS sales, 
   SUM(comission) AS comission, 
   SUM(sale_total) AS publisher_total_sale
FROM reports_summary 
   GROUP BY publisher_name 
   ORDER BY publisher_total_sale DESC
```

which outputs

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ publisher_name + | + sales + | + commission + | publisher_total_sale_count +
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ some publisher + | 254,12  + | + 12,23      + | 15                         +
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ publisher2     + | 123     + | + 23         + | 12                         +
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

what I want

another column which gives me `sum(publisher_total_sale_count)` in this example 27.
                         +
 Is it possible, how would I do this?

Comment: What's wrong with this query? Can you specify table structure, data and desired output? You'd be surprised at the amount of information that is *not* obvious from a broken query without context.

Comment: One way is with WITH ROLLUP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate that in a subquery then use a cross join to bring it into your main query:

```
SELECT 
   publisher_name, 
   SUM(sales) AS sales, 
   SUM(comission) AS comission, 
   SUM(sale_total) AS publisher_total_sale,
   sumOfTotalSales
FROM reports_summary,
   (SELECT Sum(Sales_total) as sumOfTotalSales FROM reports_summary) as subTotalSales
   GROUP BY publisher_name, sumOfTotalSales 
   ORDER BY publisher_total_sale DESC
```

To do this in the GUI instead of the SQL editor, you can create a new query that does what the subquery here is doing `SELECT Sum(Sales_total) as sumOfTotalSales FROM reports_summary` then bring that into your main query and insure that there is no join between the two tables.

Comment: this is what I want thank u. Is there a shorter query for this?

Comment: I don't believe so. This is about as short as it's going to get, and in the overall world of SQL, this is a pretty short query.